# Rails 4 / RSpec - Testing time values persisted to MYSQL database in controller specs

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, time, rspec

I'm writing pretty standard RSpec controller tests for my Rails app. One issue I'm running into is simply testing that time values have been persisted in an update action.

In my controller I have:

```
def update
  if @derp.update_attributes(derp_params)
    redirect_to @derp, flash: {success: "Updated derp successfully."}
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

@derp has a time attribute of type time. I can test all of its other attributes in the update action as follows:

```
describe "PATCH #update" do
  before do
    @attr = { 
      attribute_1: 5, attribute_2: 6, attribute_3: 7,
      time: Time.zone.now
    }
  end
end
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
1) DerpsController logged in PATCH #update updates the derps's attributes
 Failure/Error: expect(derp.time).to eq(@attr[:time])

   expected: 2015-08-24 18:30:32.096943000 -0400
        got: 2000-01-01 18:30:32.000000000 +0000

   (compared using ==)

   Diff:
   @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
   -2015-08-24 18:30:32 -0400
   +2000-01-01 18:30:32 UTC
```

I've tried using Timecop and also comparing with a to_s or to_i...but every attribute of data type time is completely off as far as the year goes. I've seen a couple posts saying how you can expect it to be within 1 second and how to deal with that, but it looks like my year is completely off?

This can't be that difficult - I just want to test that the controller can take a time sent to it and save it to the database.

What am I missing here?

EDIT: No help here after a couple of days. Let me try to re-iterate what's happening - The date is being stripped because it is a MYSQL type TIME. Notice the 2000-01-01...

Answer (score 0):

```
  let(:time) {'Mon, 24 Aug 2015 23:19:09'}
  describe "PATCH #update" do
      before do
        @attr = { 
          attribute_1: 5, attribute_2: 6, attribute_3: 7,
          time: time.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)').to_datetime
        }
      end
    end
```

Rather than saving `Time.zone.now` in the record, define a `time` variable and update the record with that time so you know which time should be saved in the database. Then, expect to get that time back when you compare.

Comment: This still isn't working for me: 

    expected: 2015-04-20 16:20:08.000000000 -0400
    got: 2000-01-01 16:20:08.000000000 +0000

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

```
let(:time) {'01 Jan 2000 16:20:00'}
```

I really can't find any good explanation as to how or why Rails is storing time as 2000-01-01, or any helper method to format a time like that. I checked the controller params and its actually being sent to the controller with that 2000-01-01 date in it.

Some people say to just use a datetime, but I am truly trying to store a time of the day, so I don't think that makes sense for this use case.

Anyway, I can just use that time variable anywhere in my specs and works.